# Can't secure empty trash in OS X

Tags: macos, trash

I'm trying to empty the trash but it shows an alert that prompts me to *Stop* or *Continue*.

When I click *Continue* it terminates the process – but how do I format or empty the trash in OS X?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting it via shell. Open *Applications » Utilities » Terminal.app*. Now you could `rm` all files from the trash – although that will not securely remove them.

To do that, enter:

```
rm -rf ~/.Trash/*
```

Make sure type to this exactly as above.

If you want to delete only the file that causes problems: Type `rm ~/.Trash/`, then enter "The" and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. The file name should be auto-completed. If you have multiple documents starting with "The", press <kbd>Tab</kbd> until the right file appears. It should look like this:

```
rm ~/.Trash/The\ Age\ Article\ -\ World Cup (rest of the filename here)
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to delete the file.